# Installed Bluez theme as a sub-theme but can't change Appearance Settings

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the [Bluez](https://www.drupal.org/project/bluez) theme (in D7). I created a sub-theme from it. It doesn't have a starter kit or anything so I just turned it into a sub-theme by creating an .info file, etc.

Things are working fine so far, but when I try to make any changes to the settings in 'Appearance' under 'Bluez Theme Settings' ... make the changes and then click 'save configuration' > it says the 'configuration options have been saved' but ... they aren't.

Any idea what might be happening here? I'm thinking maybe there are template files I should be copying over to my sub-theme folder or something. Or maybe you can't create sub-themes out of themes that don't support sub-theming?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The Bluez them does have a [bluez.info](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bluez/tree/bluez.info) file; I am not sure what you mean when you say you created a .info file. What name did you give to the .info file? Is the name given to the .info file used consistently through the new theme?

Comment: Also, if you changed the code of the Bluez theme to create your own theme, you should show the changes you made; otherwise is difficult to answer it. I can imagine why the settings are apparently not saved, but without to see the changes you make, it's not possible to point out what you did wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the follow-up. What I mean is that I created a blank folder in my sites/all/templates folder called my_bluez and created a .info file in their called my_bluez.info and put the relevant info in there, ie. name = My Bluez
description = A corporate theme with pre-defined configurable slider, blocks and Footer options. Developed by <a href="http://in.linkedin.com/in/ujvalshah">Ujval Shah</a>
core = 7.x
base theme = bluez
engine = phptemplate

Comment: So I otherwise just copied and pasted what was in the base theme .info file into my_bluez .info file. I set my_bluez as the template but in appearance I can't make any changes that save to either the slider text or to the blocks below the slider...both of which have options in the appearance settings. I even removed where it sets the default settings for those in my .info file and flushed my cache...but it still doesn't work. I didn't make any other changes to the theme...I copied in some images and gave my own logo and that was it.  I added some content types and content within also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of your comments you wrote you created your my_bluez folder within the "*sites/all/templates folder*".

If that's really the name of the folder where you created the my_bluez subfolder (i.e. that it is not a typo in your comment here), then I wonder what result you would get if you would rename that folder to "*sites/all/themes*". Because that would make it comply with the [Community documentation about Installing themes](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/install-contrib/themes) (bullet 3 in that list there). It would make it even  harder to realize for Drupal that my_bluez theme is actually like a clone of the Bluez theme, no?. Just to be sure, after renaming that foled I'd then also clear the Drupal cache.

If that still doesn't work, then I wond if it could be related to some (missing) file permissions of that newly created folder.

Does this help somehow?

PS: Creating a "clone" seems to me like a better term of what you're trying to achieve. [Creating a sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) is really something related to base themes in Drupal-eze.